# Render issue in FireFox

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, firefox

I am working on a website and I found a bug in firefox, that I cannot seem to fix. Whenever I hard refresh, the div centers perfectly (although there is a frame in which it stutters). However when I refresh normally, the div is completely to the left.

The correct version:
[image: The working version]

The version in FF (and IE):
[image]

I tried multiple things, but I cannot find the bug. Funny enough, in Internet explorer 11, the div element isn't even shown.

What can cause this seemingly weird behaviour?

Click [here](http://kookhulpje.nl/welkom.php) to have a look at the online version of the website.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd say you've got more CSS than you'd need. You should also set a width and height for the banner_text container, that way you can center it with left, right, bottom and top set to 0, or how it's originally done using flex.

Remove `<img src="img/banner.jpg" alt="banner">` and `<div class="banner_overlay"></div>`

And then for your CSS you can do the following:

```
.banner {
    width: 100%;
    height: 400px;
    position: relative;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    background-image: url('http://kookhulpje.nl/img/banner.jpg');
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center center;
}

.banner::before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: rgba(72, 25, 48, 0.5);
}

.banner .banner_text {
    background: rgba( 255, 255, 255, 0.6);
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 2;
    border-left: 4px solid #fff;
    border-right: 4px solid #fff;
    width: 470px;
    height: 90px;
}
```

This fixes the main problem, but I think you've got javascript that's conflicting with the banner, for some reason when you zoom in or out the width for the banner hangs, so everything within it doesn't adjust correctly on firefox at least. I haven't finished taking a look into it.